# RegEx for limited decimal

Tags: c#, regex

New to regex syntax here. Trying to write a regex to provide some input validation.

What I need is a regex to match a whole number, or a decimal with exactly one digit past the decimal.

```
Good Match
1
12
100
1.1
100.1
1.0

No Match
1.22
1.
0
012
```

Here is what I came up with but it doesn't work:

```
Regex.IsMatch(paidHours, "\\d+[.]?[0-9]?")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited answer after OP question edit.**

```
Regex.IsMatch(paidHours, @"^[1-9][0-9]*(\.[0-9])?$");
```

Explanation:

```
^      : Start of the String
[1-9]  : A single number between 1 and 9
[0-9]* : Zero or more number(s) between 0 and 9 
         ([0-9]? would match zero or one number and the String "100" would not match the regex)
(      : Start of a group
\.     : A point
[0-9]  : A single number between 0 and 9
)?     : End of the group. The group must be repeated zero or one time
$      : End of the String
```

Please note that `\d` is not *exactly* equivalent to `[0-9]`: `\d` matches any [unicode digit](http://fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm). For instance, this character `௮` will be matched if you use `\d` but won't be if you use `[0-9]`.

Comment: @Otiel are you sure that there is no need to escape `.` ?

Comment: @Otiel: you do need to escape, otherwise it will match also `!@#$%^&*()` etc.

Comment: @Y.Shoham: Yes you're right, I confused parenthesis `( )` and brackets `[ ]` rules. Edited the answer.

Comment: Very nice, thank you. I forgot to include the requirement though to also "No Match" on 0 or 012 (see edit above). I tried to change the beginning to ^[1-9] but then of course it will not match on 10 or 20 etc.

Comment: Works, thank you again. Question for my own understanding, why did you use "\*" instead of "?" after the first sequence? "^[1-9][0-9]*"

Comment: @EkoostikMartin: See the explanations in my edit. And you're welcome :)

Answer (score 3):

You can try with:

```
Regex.IsMatch(paidHours, "^\\d+(\\.\\d)?$")
```

Comment: +1 for the pattern. I'd encourage you to add anchors though to avoid possible `a1.11bc`.

Answer (score 3):

```
Regex.IsMatch(paidHours, @"^\d+(\.\d)?$")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify beggining/end of the line:

```
@"^\d+[.]?[0-9]?$"
```

You regex won't work since ie 1.234 was a match wit 1.2, if you don't specify you want the string ends with the `'$'` sign.